# Modifying constant object

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, undefined-behavior

I was looking through the interview questions to a junior C++ developer position. The question is (quote):

> Is the following code **correct**?

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    void foo ( void ) const
    {
        Foo* pointer = const_cast<Foo*>(this);
        pointer->i = 0;
    }
};
```

I would answer:

> The code itself is valid according to the C++03 and c++11 standards and will compile successfully.
>   But it may invoke an undefined behavior during assignment **pointer->i
>   = 0;** if the instance of the class on which **foo()** is being called is declared as **const**.

I mean that following code will compile successfully and result in undefined behaviour.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    Foo ( void )
    {

    }
    void foo ( void ) const
    {
        Foo* pointer = const_cast<Foo*>(this);
        pointer->i = 0;
    }
};

int main ( void )
{
    Foo foo1;
    foo1.foo();   // Ok

    const Foo foo2;
    foo2.foo();   // UB

    return 0;
}
```

Is my answer correct or I am missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: "Correct" is rather a vague word. It's *well-formed*, meaning it has no diagnosable errors, but (as you say) could cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: IMO from a design POV it's not "correct" because `const Foo foo; foo.foo();` should not be UB. Using a `mutable` member would be better.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I agree, these are related questions. I just wanted to ensure I did get everything correct. Am I supposed to delete the question?

Comment: The follow-up question, given that you passed the first, would be: give an example of when `const_cast` is both safe and practical to use that isn't a toy example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first ask what is meant by their ambiguous definition of "correct". You need to know the specification of the program and its **intended behaviour**.

As you said, if they're just asking if it compiles then the answer is 'yes'. However, if they determine correct to be safe to do, then you can discuss the facts that you state in your question.

By answering this way, the person interviewing can see how that you're analysing what you're being asked, rather than jumping straight into answering, which in my opinion is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This code may be legally correct, but I guess, the aim of the question is to determine, whether you understood the concept of const itself. Because, on the semantic level, you have a function taking an implicit const object pointer, which it then goes to modify, which is almost certainly a bug.

There are cases, where this may be desired (because the modification is some caching of return values, or similar operation that does not change the semantic value of the object), you would use the `mutable` keyword for the variable in question.

Comment: Thank you. This is nice idea to mention in the answer that declaring `i` as `mutable` will fix the mentioned possible UB.

Comment: Removing *constness* is a sign of bug in design. Then, you start to analyze the consequences of this.

Answer (score 0):

cheating complier will take the consequences.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;

    Foo(int a):i(a){}

    void foo ( void ) const
    {
        Foo* pointer = const_cast<Foo*>(this);
        pointer->i = 0;
    }

    bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const{
        return i<rhs.i;
    }
};

#include <map>

int main ( void )
{
    std::map<Foo,int> kk;

    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        kk.insert(std::make_pair(Foo(i),i));
    }

    std::map<Foo,int>::iterator ite = kk.find(Foo(4));
    const Foo& foo4 = ite->first;
    foo4.foo();

    ite = kk.find(Foo(4));
    const Foo& tmp = ite->first; // crack

    return 0;
}
```

program will crack at "const Foo& tmp = ite->first;"