# A const & refers to a nonvolatile variable. The variable changes. Does the change invalidate the const &?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, undefined-behavior, const-reference

In C++, can the value of a `const &` change?

Well, of course it cannot change, can it? That's what `const` means. Moreover, listen to Stroustrup:

> A `const` lvalue reference refers to a constant, which is immutable from the point of view of the user of the reference.

But what about this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int           a = 0;
    const int&    r = a;
    const int old_r = r;
    ++a;
    const int new_r = r;
    std::cout
      <<      "old_r == " << old_r
      << " but new_r == " << new_r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this outputs, `old_r == 0 but new_r == 1`.

That gets to my real question. In the above code, look at the line

```
    const int new_r = r;
```

Insofar as

- the address `&new_r` is extracted neither on this line nor elsewhere in the code and
- the code has nothing `volatile`,

does anything prevent an optimizing compiler from merging `old_r` and `new_r` into a single constant object, treating the line as though it read as follows?

```
    const int& new_r = old_r;
```

I ask because, as far as I know, if the compiler did so optimize, that might alter the behavior. The program might output, `old_r == 0 but new_r == 0`.

**RELATED QUESTIONS**

The most nearly related existing question I find is this one:

- (C language) [**Can const be changed?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18759500/1275653) (See especially the linked question's point no. 1.)

The following are also related but, unlike the present question, involve casts:

- [Changing the value of a const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/583076/1275653)
- [Two different values at the same memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3593687/1275653)
- [Modifying constant object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17833558/1275653)
- [Changing the value of const variable [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006161/1275653)
- (C language) [Accessing a non-const through const declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8051969/1275653)
- (C language) [Can we modify the value of a const variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12245333/1275653)
- (C language) [Const variable value is changed by using a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18416733/1275653)
- (C language) [Confusion regarding modification of const variable using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21372713/1275653)
- (C language) [Weird Behaviour with const_cast [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22391423/1275653)

See also [N4659](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (draft C++17 standard), sect. 10.1.7.1, "The *cv-qualifiers.*"

The quote of Stroustrup at the top of the question comes from sect. 7.7.2 of *The C++ Programming Language,* 4th ed. Of course, no author can write every sentence perfectly in a thousand-page book; yet perhaps Stroustrup is clear and I have merely read him wrong. Nevertheless, you might see why the sentence has confused me. This is why I have asked.

Comment: Sure it can, and this is also one of the reasons `const T&` arguments make a function harder to optimize compared to passing the same arguments by-value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C++, can the value of a `const &` change?

Yes, but not through that reference (ignoring `mutable` fields).

```
void foo(const int& c, int& mut) {
    std::cout << c << " ";
    ++mut; // changes `c` if &c == &mut
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
int a = 42;
foo(a, a); // 42 43
```

> does anything prevent an optimizing compiler from merging old_r and new_r into a single constant object, treating the line as though it read as follows?

The as-if rule allows compiler to optimize if visible side effect are the same,
which is **not** the case here. So your "proposed merge of variable" in your code cannot be done fortunately.

Comment: Aha. I see. It's the visible side effect rule. I think that that makes sense. I had the idea that a `const &` ought to imply, semantically, that the symbol referenced an unchanging object, and that the compiler might rely on this implication. You say however that this is not the case. Except with locks and atomics in threaded code, I had never had reason to use a `const &` to a nonvolatile but nevertheless changing object. Your answer is therefore illuminating.

Comment: Is there any way in C++ to invite a compiler to assume that an object identified via reference won't change, in cases where the programmer knows that to be the case?  In C99, one could indicate that with a `const*restrict` pointer, but I'm unaware of any concept similar to `restrict` in C++.

Comment: @supercat: There are no `restrict` is the standard. (but compilers generally provide equivalent as `__restrict__`).

Answer (score 9):

> In C++, can the value of a const & change?

Yes, this is perfectly legal.  Taking a `const&` to some variable doesn't stop that variable from being able to be modified, it just means you can't modify the variable through the reference.  That means

```
int a = 42;
int const& b = a;
++a;
std::cout << a << " " << b;
```

will print

```
43 43
```

Had I tried to do

```
++b;
```

though that would be a compiler error as `b`'s access to the value is `const` and `++` is a non const operation.

Comment: This is the right answer. Threads and volatility aren't necessary to changing the value.

Answer (score 4):

> Well, of course it cannot change, can it? That's what const means.

No, it isn't.

`const` means *you* can't change the thing. It doesn't mean it won't change. It doesn't mean it's a constant.

`const` just gives you an immutable view of a thing. There may be other views of that thing, and those may be mutable.

> does anything prevent an optimizing compiler from merging old_r and new_r into a single constant object

Yes: the fact that one of them would have the wrong value.

Comment: You have shown that my phrasing incorrectly expresses my intent. Thanks for the tip. I have reworded the relevant part of the question.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've changed the premise of the question, which is that you think binding a `const` reference introduces a guarantee that the referent won't be changed. This was originally quite clearly stated but is now more subtle. If that's no longer the premise of the question then could you please clarify the rest of it also? Why would this be undefined behaviour? What do you think `const` does exactly?

Comment: No, you have correctly understood the premise. The original question attracted +2 upvotes but also -2 downvotes, unexplained. The edit is my blind attempt to make the question more bland so that downvotes do not bury it. Cheek earns downvotes on SO. That's all.

Comment: You have already been generous with your time, so I would not further impose. However, were you inclined to edit the question, the edit would be appreciated. Sometimes it's hard to strike just the right tone.

Comment: Heh, IRTA "you have _incorrectly_ understood the premise" first time around :P

Comment: Yeah I'd just put it back the way it was tbh. That statement you edited out (which I quoted) seems to be the absolute core of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the const values can change. When you do

```
const int&    r = a;
```

you are creating a reference to a const int. The code that gets to use this variable will not be allowed to change the value via the reference. But it in no way suggests that the value stored there will not change.

See it as a variable with read-only permission. Some other piece of code might have write access.

You should compare with `constexpr` which are truly constant expressions.

Comment: The second sentence in this answer is already part of the confusion I believe, as a `const int` certainly cannot change  - so why should it be able to change when you form a reference to it? (The "const int" in "reference to const int" is not exactly the same as the "const int" in a `const int`, see reference binding.) The distinction is very subtle so I would prefer to elaborate on this wording.